# How can I use UserDefaults to store from UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker, ibaction

I am new to programming and to Swift. The app I'm building is vary simple and I want to add a simple local notification, triggered by a UIDatePicker that is set by the user. I've managed to set up the notification but I'm on my knees trying to understand how to keep the UIDatePicker from reseting each time I restart the app. Here's the relevant code (without the stuff going on in AppDelegate.swift):

```
 @IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let selectedDate = sender.date
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    delegate?.scheduleNotification(at: selectedDate)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Date` does not conform to `NSCoding`, you cannot directly store it in user defaults. You need to convert it to a "property list type" (which means the type of things you can store in a property list, `Int`, `Double`, `String`, `Dictionary` etc). In this case, you will convert the `Date` to a `Double`:

```
let selectedDate = sender.date
let timeSince1970 = selectedDate.timeIntervalSince1970
// now we have the double value, we can store it in user defaults! :)
UserDefaults.standard.set(timeSince1970, forKey: "myDate")
```

EDIT:

Oops! It seems like I got this one wrong, you *can* actually directly store a `Date` in User Defaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedDate, forKey: "myDate")
```

To get back the stored date and set it as the selected date of the date picker, simply do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let selectedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myDate") as? Date
myDatePickerOutlet.setDate(selectedDate ?? Date(), animated: false)
```

If you stored a `Double` as the date, you can retrieve it like this:

```
let selectedDate = Date(
    timeIntervalSince1970: UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "myDate"))
```

Comment: Can't seem to make it work. You have a "myDatePickerOutlet" in your code, but I only have an IBAction from my UIDatePicker. I tried just adding an IBOutlet from my UIDatePicker but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @RichardRenklint you can't *just* add an outlet. You need an outlet _and_ an action

Comment: Ok. So how do I add it the correct way without messing up my notification? Also, I'm not sure if I should put the code inside the "IBAction func datePicker" or not.

Comment: @RichardRenklint put the code that saves the date in the IBAction method, put the code that retrieves the date in the viewDidLoad method. And just add an outlet! Control drag the date picker in the storyboard to your view controller.